# android studio - object moving and dragging

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I'm new to use Android Studio and I got a few questions about this program:

1. How can I move objects (for example: button) on the app layout with the nagivation keys?
2. According to [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZJOv.jpg), when I'm trying to drag only the textView it's dragging the textView with the editText like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuu0p.jpg).

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: include your xml then we can help you

Comment: those questions are not about the application it's about how to use Android Studio correctly.

Comment: @WolesMe its more about how your Views are bound together than how Android Studio works, I asked for xml so I could see if you views are bound together then I can suggest you changes